# MySQL InnoDB in catch-22 in MAMP

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mamp, mamp-pro

Now my title might be a bit fuzzy, but let me explain.

I am using MAMP Pro to create a wordpress website locally. But I got an error a while ago `InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35` that then  told me that by removing `ibdata1` could possibly solve the problem. I believe since then I have had some trouble with using MySQL.

Now after a bit of work on another project I am back on this problem and therefore my memory isn't the best. I have read up online for about two days, trying different 'solutions' to my problem. I have now focused my problem down to five tables in the database `mysql` called:

- `mysql.innodb_index_stats`
- `mysql.innodb_table_stats`
- `mysql.slave_master_info`
- `mysql.slave_relay_log_info`
- `mysql.slave_worker_info`

These tables are in a catch 22 it seems like. I have tried at several times (with restarting servers in between tries) to:

- Remove the `.frm` and `.ibd` files from `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/mysql`
- Change permissions of mentioned path above to chmod 755
- Reinstalling MAMP Pro with no effect.
- I have tried setting `innodb_stats_persistent = 0` in `my.cnf`.
- Recreate the affected tables as shown on the answer on: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54624.

But this is where it gets tricky. When I create a table as suggested in many posts, it gives me the error of: `Tablespace for table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.` for example. So I then go on a search for how to discard the tablespace and come up with many answers, including `ALTER TABLE mysql.innodb_index_stats DISCARD TABLESPACE;`. This gives me another error: `Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist`.

**That is where my catch 22 is.**

Do you know how to solve this?

I have also tried to create the table under a temporary name successfully as mentioned by Sam in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=609156 and then unsuccessfully renamed it to the non-existant (from my knowledge) table `mysql.innodb_index_stats`. Just have to mention that the problem could also be tied to an unplanned upgrade from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6.35

Now I have scoured all of the relevant first pages on google for my problem but to no avail. I have found two other comments mentioning the same thing as me, but no answers. That is why I'm lifting it forward in a more explained and dedicated post so that people can find it. Please tell me if I should edit anything in my post, this is my first one here.

Comment: Do _not_ play around with _any_ of MySQL's files other than `my.cnf`.  Deleting `ibdata1` destroys all InnoDB tables.  Etc.

Comment: That was a mistake I learned the hard way :/ 
Is there any way that I can fix this @RickJames? 
Could I possibly download a new instance of the DB ´mysql´ or how do I go from here?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry, your data seems to be gone.  You have mentioned about 3 disastrous actions already taken.  Even uninstalling may be difficult at this point.

Comment: Even though I have dumps on my important databases, the data should be able to be imported on a fresh MySQL install, no? Any chance you have an idea on how to freshly install the `mysql` database? It didn't seem like downloading the latest (4.2.1) MAMP did any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved my problem. What I did was to run the uninstaller included in the MAMP PRO folder. Delete the MAMP folder and then empty the trash (the digital one). 
I then downloaded a fresh installation of MAMP PRO which was recently updated to 4.3.0 where MySQL also was updated to 5.6.38.
This finally gave me a fresh `mysql` database including `ibdata1` and all of the aforementioned corrupt tables, but now without any errors.

Hope this helps anyone in need!